# Detect browser back to prevent user from losing unsaved data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history

I know that I should not override the behavior of the back button but I just want to warn the user that he should save his form data before leaving the page.

I made that for the page refreh like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            if (myData.hasChanges()) {
                return "Data unsaved.";
            }
        };
```

but this isn't fired on back button click because my application use [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) for navigation. I'm only updating parts of the page using ajax. Not doing a full post back...

How should I do to show an alert to the user?

I would like toi have a behaviour like [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/): when I write something to the code blocks and click the back button, an alert is shown...